# Select entries with a specific attribute but that have never had this attribute

Tags: sql, sas

I am using SAS and I would like to select all of my clients who have status B but who did not have status B before a specific date.

My data is structured like this:

| CLIENT | STATUS | PURCHASE_DATE | ACTUAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 05/01/2021 | N |
| 1 | A | 05/02/2021 | N |
| 1 | B | 05/03/2021 | Y |
| 2 | B | 12/02/2021 | N |
| 2 | B | 07/04/2021 | Y |

And this is my attempt. What am I doing wrong?

```
PROC SQL;
       CREATE want AS 
       SELECT t1.CLIENT
          FROM WORK.HAVE t1
          WHERE t1.STATUS = 'B' AND ACTUAL = 'Y' AND  ( t1.PURCHASE_DATE < '4Mar2021'd AND t1.STATUS NOT = 'B' );
    QUIT;
```

Comment: All of your dates are after March first.  Or are those ambiguous strings you posted supposed represent fifth of January instead of May first?  Please clarify and show what output you expect for that input.

Comment: Make sure to include some clients that fail to meet your criteria for selection.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest aggregation:

```
PROC SQL;
   SELECT h.CLIENT
   FROM WORK.HAVE h
   WHERE h.STATUS = 'B' AND h.ACTUAL = 'Y'
   GROUP BY h.CLIENT
   HAVING MIN(PURCHASE_DATE) >= '4Mar2021'd 
   ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL this should work. Select `CLIENT`s which obtained status 'B' not earlier then '4Mar2021' (provided this is correct date literal in your DBMS).

```
      SELECT t1.CLIENT
      FROM WORK.HAVE t1
      WHERE t1.STATUS = 'B' AND t1.ACTUAL = 'Y' 
          AND t1.PURCHASE_DATE >= '4Mar2021'
          AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                          FROM WORK.HAVE t2
                          WHERE t2.CLIENT = t1.CLIENT AND t2.STATUS = 'B' AND t2.PURCHASE_DATE < t1.PURCHASE_DATE)
```